# How can I get output data of a trained neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, javascript

My neural network, which uses the back-propagation technique and the sigmoid activation function, should 'learn' the sine function.

This is the networks structure:
[image]

The following code should train the network with 1000 datasets:

[image]

After that, I try to draw a sine with this piece of code:
[image]

The output is quite disappointing, compared to a real sine wave:
[image]

I hope, someone could give me a hint.
Thank you.

**Edit:**

The problem was solved (see answer by Richard Hardy).
I made this interactive website for testing the network:
http://norizon.li/repo/neural-net/

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "real data"?

Comment: By real data, I mean the output value. In this test case, I am using x as input and the output should be sin(x).

Comment: Have you considered transforming your data to fit into the [0,1] interval? $\frac{sin(x)+1}{2}$ will fit into [0,1] for any $x$.

Comment: @RichardHardy I've just tried this. It does not seem to work, but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: The transformation itself must work, so perhaps the problem lies elsewhere. Could you rephrase your question and/or give more details on what you are doing (step by step)? Perhaps then it will be easier to see what the trouble is.

Comment: Okay, I've rephrased the question.

Comment: Hmm, the output does look like a real $\operatorname{sin}$ wave, doesn't it? But is it possible to help you without reading your whole code? Or are you actually expecting us to find a coding mistake? I still miss a little explanation in words.

Comment: The output is the white line. The gray line is a sine wave, yes. I only need to know whether these two snippets are correct or wrong. I will add an explanation of how the network works. Thank you.

Comment: @RichardHardy I have rewritten the script and tested it with the XOR function. Basically, you've answered my question ("Have you considered transforming your data to fit into the [0,1] interval"). It works. Could you please post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considered transforming your data to fit into the [0,1] interval.

For the $\operatorname{sin}(x)$ case, $\frac{ \operatorname{sin}(x) + 1}{ 2 }$ will fit into [0,1] for any $x$.